# Angular Observable - Get value from response

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am new to working with Angular Observable objects and am trying to make a call to my backend webservice, and build a list of objects from the response that is returned.

The response is as follows:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": [
    {
        "type": "SUCCESS",
        "message": "Successfully retrieved BoM Master info.",
        "title": "SUCCESS",
        "userVisible": true
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
        "pKey": {
            "winetype": "BFB200CAL",
            "validOn": "05/16/2017"
        },
        "wineTypeDesc": "MUSC/BAR BBLY",
        ...
    }
  ]
}
```

And i have a class mapped to the format of the objects in the "data" array.

And the service class is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BomMasterSpec } from './bom-master-spec.model';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class BomMasterSpecsService {
  private url = `${environment.webServiceBaseURL}/BomMasterSpecs/Active/11-22-2017`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getMasterSpecs(): Observable<BomMasterSpec[]> {
    return this.http.get<BomMasterSpec[]>(this.url);
  }
}
```

The issue i am having is in the service, I cannot figure out how to extract the "data" array from the response returned by the server and map it to an array of "BomMasterSpec" objects. I believe i need to use the .pipe(map()) type of call, but everything i have tried thus far has been unsuccessful.

Can anyone provide an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the data returned by your observable as

```
return this.http.get<BomMasterSpec[]>.pipe(map(res => res.data as BomMasterSpec[]));
```

You can see this in action at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-transform-observable

If you always have a same outer skeleton for all your service calls having properties like status etc., you should look at creating generic data type which you can typecast based on what service method you are calling.

Comment: I still get that `error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'BomMasterSpec[]'` message every time it recompiles, but that line of code does indeed work.